# Why I get undefined when I use react redux RTK query useByIdQuery

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, rtk-query

I created store where are a all endpoints and I have a issues with getById endpoint.

Store.tsx

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";
import { Character } from "../interface/types";

export const characterAPI = createApi({
  reducerPath: "characterAPI",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: "https://www.breakingbadapi.com/api/" }),
  tagTypes: ["Characters"],
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getAll: builder.query<Character[], void>({
      query: () => `characters`,
      providesTags: [{ type: "Characters", id: "LIST" }],
    }),
    getById: builder.query<Character, string>({
      query: (char_id) => `characters/${char_id}`,
      providesTags: [{ type: "Characters", id: "LIST" }],
    }),
  }),
});
```

CharacterContainer.tsx

But after loading I can see whole data, but when i wanna console.log(getById) its's says undefined

```
import React from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { characterAPI } from "../store/store";

const CharacterContainer = () => {
  const { char_id } = useParams();
  const { data: getById, isLoading } = characterAPI.useGetByIdQuery(
    char_id as string
  );
  
  console.log(getById);

  const { name, birthday } = getById || {};
  if (isLoading) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{name}</p>
      <p>{birthday}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

And what I see in tools:

```
CharacterContainer.tsx:22  undefined
CharacterContainer.tsx:22  undefined
CharacterContainer.tsx:22 
[{…}]0: appearance: (5) [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
better_call_saul_appearance: []
birthday: "09-07-1958"
category: "Breaking Bad"
char_id: 1
img: "https://images.amcnetworks.com/amc.com/wpcontent/uploads/2015/04/cast_bb_700x1000_walter-white-lg.jpg"
name: "Walter White"
nickname: "Heisenberg"
occupation: (2)
 ['High School Chemistry Teacher', 'Meth King Pin']
portrayed: "Bryan Cranston"status: 
"Presumed dead"[[Prototype]]: Objectlength: 1[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are trying to console.log the result immediately, and this means you are trying to output getById when the query is still in it's loading phase. You could do something like:

```
console.log(isLoading ? "Loading result" : getById)
```

Your output would then be something like:

```
CharacterContainer.tsx:22  undefined
CharacterContainer.tsx:22  undefined
CharacterContainer.tsx:22 
[{…}]0: appearance: (5) [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
better_call_saul_appearance: []
birthday: "09-07-1958"
category: "Breaking Bad"
char_id: 1
img: "https://images.amcnetworks.com/amc.com/wpcontent/uploads/2015/04/cast_bb_700x1000_walter-white-lg.jpg"
name: "Walter White"
nickname: "Heisenberg"
occupation: (2)
 ['High School Chemistry Teacher', 'Meth King Pin']
portrayed: "Bryan Cranston"status: 
"Presumed dead"[[Prototype]]: Objectlength: 1[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```